# Instrumenting for value changes of variables using gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, instrumentation

I found that we could use `-finstrument-functions` in gcc for instrumentation to find function call sequences. Is there a way to do instrumentation (using gcc options or plugins) similarly to find out the changes in the values of individual data variables as well?

Comment: This isn't a "how to" site.

Comment: That is possible with LLVM, so it should also be possible with gcc (for example, the -fgnu-tm instruments loads and stores for its own needs). Depending on what your goals is, an alternative could be to use dynamic binary instrumentation with Intel Pin or Dyninst. That might be faster to prototype something.

Comment: @WeatherVane, what kind of site is it? and what isn't a "how to"?

Comment: I found [this guy's solution](http://linuxgazette.net/151/melinte.html) that, using the `-finstrument-functions`, extracts the arguments and return values.